# Java Spring RestTemplate get 1 object from api

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I keep running into an issue and I can't seem to find the solution anywhere.
I have an api that responds with an object EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse. This is a single object that has the user's info like his name and roles inside of it. There can only be 1 response and so it will always send 1.

This is the code in the controller of the rest api:

```
@GetMapping("/authenticate")
public EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse getAuthenticated(@RequestHeader(value = "email") String requestMail, @RequestHeader(value = "password") String requestPassword){
    return employeeService.signin(requestMail, requestPassword);
}
```

This is what I use to try and retrieve it:

```
public class LoginController {
    @FXML
    private Label errorText;
    @FXML
    private TextField email;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;

    @FXML
    protected void login(ActionEvent event) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if(email != null && email.getText() != "" && password != null && password.getText() != ""){

            //Hash password before sending it out(This is just extra for during the connection, the server hashed it again with Bcrypt)
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] digest = md.digest(password.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String passwordHash = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1,digest));

            //Initiate Spring stuff
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

            //maak headers
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.add("user-agent", "My app");
            headers.add("email", email.getText());
            headers.add("password", passwordHash);
            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>("parameters", headers);

            //Send it away and retrieve
            ResponseEntity<EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse> loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/employee/authenticate", HttpMethod.GET, entity, EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse.class);

            //If else stuffs
            if(loginResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
                errorText.setText("it works");
            } else if(loginResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
                errorText.setText("wrong password");
            } else if(loginResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT){
                errorText.setText("error");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now when I try to use this I get some warnings and an error.
First "warning"

```
18:04:56.170 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter - Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class link.to.class.DTO.EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse]]
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public link.to.class.EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse() accessible: module link.to.class does not "exports link.to.class.DTO" to unnamed module @13f33d2d
```

It then gives some extra info:

```
18:04:56.171 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[]
18:04:56.173 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [parameters] as "application/json"
18:04:56.683 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
```

And then it gives the same failed to evaluate Jackson Deserialization for type warning twice, then I get a Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type error/exception, which is where it ends.

I have looked up a lot around Stack overflow and other sites, when I add [] behind EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse like:

```
ResponseEntity<EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse[]> loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/employee/authenticate", HttpMethod.GET, entity, EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse[].class);
```

I go straight to the exception without the warnings. This makes me think that the issue is that I need to have a list as a response and not a single object when using RestTemplate like this, but then how do I get a single entity? Everything I can find online is about consuming lists.

EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse {
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeFirstName;
    private String employeeLastName;
    private int employeeDarkMode;
    private int employeeRoleId;
    private String employeeRoleName;
    private int employeePermissionSales;
    private int employeePermissionSending;
    private int employeePermissionManager;
    private int employeePermissionProductManagement;
    private String JWTToken;

//Getters and setters

}
```

The Json:

```
{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "employeeFirstName": "TestFname",
    "employeeLastName": "TestLname",
    "employeeDarkMode": 1,
    "employeeRoleId": 1,
    "employeeRoleName": "owner",
    "employeePermissionSales": 1,
    "employeePermissionSending": 1,
    "employeePermissionManager": 1,
    "employeePermissionProductManagement": 1,
    "jwttoken": "JWTTOKEN"
}
```

Module-info.java:

```
module com.windsoftware.kassa.windkassadesktop {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires validatorfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.web;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;

    opens link.to.class to javafx.fxml;
    exports link.to.class;
    exports link.to.class.controllers;
    opens link.to.class.controllers to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Comment: Show us the EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse class

Comment: @Bahij.Mik Added it.

Comment: also pls add the json that you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: @eis Added the json response too. It is litterally EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse. The class is a copy paste from the API into the application. I hoped that would make it work.

Comment: Looking at the error again, are you using java 9+? it seems object mapper is failing because of not having access to the class module through reflection

Comment: hmm. So you really should be using `EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse.class`, don't use `[]` in there. Try with `HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers); ResponseEntity<EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse> loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/employee/authenticate", HttpMethod.GET, entity, EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse.class);`

Comment: @eis I have now, and it does not seem to fix it, also the warnings that dissapear with the ```[]``` are there.

Comment: @Bahij.Mik Running Java 16.0.1

Comment: Are you using modules? @Mr Dany

Comment: @Bahij.Mik Spring is in my Modules, but for some reason the ```@Bean``` and ```@Autowired``` annotations are not recognized. I use maven to import stuff and though Spring is in there it does not want to use it for some reason.

Comment: Show us the module

Comment: @Bahij.Mik Sorry but I do not have a specific module. When I go to Project Structure in InteliJ it says spring is in there but it has no application contexts defined. I am fairly new at this, sorry.

Comment: By module I mean Java modularity - something like this:
module myModule{
    exports DTO;
} 
Usually named module-info.java
@Mr Dany

Comment: @Bahij.Mik I do not have seperate modules. I have 1 application, that's it. The rest api is running completely seperately. I don't use models in any way.

Comment: modules and not models - anyway can you show the project structure? what do you have under main->java , also search for a file module-info.java to see if it is available. @Mr Dany

Comment: Check my answer @Mr Dany

Comment: @Bahij.Mik Under main java I have a the packaging going to my java code, which currently has a starter class and 2 packages, 1 with dto and 1 with controllers for fxml (which is where this is in too). The module-info.java is also under main->java

Comment: @Mr Dany can you show us module-info.java

Comment: @Bahij.Mik added that

Comment: @Mr Dany add `exports  link.to.class.DTO;`

Comment: @Bahij.Mik I don't know why, but that seems to work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! it would be nice if you can pick my solution as correct - I will change it to talk about the issue

Comment: ah, please also add to the question that you were using java 16. that was key information missing from the original question.

Comment: @eis Sorry, I didn't know Java 16 was that different from other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Java 16, you have to export your DTO package inside your module setup in order for the jackson object mapper inside the rest template to have access to your DTO class and its fields for reflection

Module-info.java:

```
module com.windsoftware.kassa.windkassadesktop {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.web;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires validatorfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.web;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;

    opens link.to.class to javafx.fxml;
    exports link.to.class;
    exports link.to.class.controllers;
    exports link.to.class.DTO;
    opens link.to.class.controllers to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might  with  the object deSerialization **EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse**

```
ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

or

```
String loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class).getBody();
```

use this and log the loginResponse then you will get the idea about the object issue

Comment: The issue is indeed with the deserialization of EmployeeAuthenticatedResponse. Using that I will get the json object as string. I do know the api works as I have tested it with postman. Any suggestions on how to make the deserialization work right?